# Import Error related to Yahoo Finance tool / html5lib install

Tags: python, pandas, scrape, yahoo-finance

I am trying to get stock data from Yahoo! Finance. I have it installed (`c:\ pip install yahoo-finance`), but the import in the iPython console is not working. This is the error I get: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 4: invalid start byte`.

I am using Python 3.4 and Spyder 2.3.1.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Update:

The unicode error during import is no longer, but now it is replaced with the following when trying to use the yahoo_finance tool...

ImportError: html5lib not found, please install it

However, html5lib is listed when I run help('modules').

Comment: Thanks TigerHawkT3 for your edits, much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error about `html5lib` with Python 3.4 in PyCharm 4.5.3, even though I installed `html5lib`. When I restarted PyCharm console (where I run the code), the error disappeared and options loaded correctly.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I will give it a try.